# Как определить что заведение открыто (работа со временем в swift)?

Tags: swift, дата, datetime

Необходимо определить открыто ли заведение в данный момент времени или закрыто, не могу понять, как это сделать, прошу помочь.

Есть массив заведение и в нем поля name="ООО Магазин 44", open="12:00", close="01:30"
Как определить открыто ли заведение сейчас или закрыто?

Comment: Сравнить now с open и close.

Answer (score 1):

Можно как-то так:

```
var beginDate = Date()
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: beginDate)
if let currentHour = components.hour, let currentMinutes = components.minute, let currentSeconds = components.second {
    beginDate = beginDate - secondsIn(hours: currentHour) - secondsIn(minutes: currentMinutes) - TimeInterval(currentSeconds)
}

let openTime = "10:00"
let closeTime = "01:30"

let openTimeArray = openTime.components(separatedBy: ":")
let closeTimeArray = closeTime.components(separatedBy: ":")

if let openHour = Int(openTimeArray[0]), let openMin = Int(openTimeArray[1]),
    let closeHour = Int(closeTimeArray[0]), let closeMin = Int(closeTimeArray[1]) {

    let openDate = beginDate + secondsIn(hours: openHour) + secondsIn(minutes: openMin)
    let closeDate = beginDate + secondsIn(hours: closeHour) + secondsIn(minutes: closeMin) + TimeInterval(closeHour < openHour ? 24*60*60 : 0)
    let currentDate = Date()

    print(currentDate >= openDate && currentDate <= closeDate)
}

func secondsIn(hours: Int) -> TimeInterval {
    return TimeInterval(hours*3600)
}

func secondsIn(minutes: Int) -> TimeInterval {
    return TimeInterval(minutes*60)
}
```